# MS SQL Merge two queries to get One Result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I am implementing a vehicle management system. I have two different queries, one for fetching all vehicles of an agency and one for fetching drivers. Every vehicle is has a driver assigned to it at a time.
Now I want to merge these two queries to returns vehicles details along with details of the driver assigned to the vehicle.

1st query to get drivers and their names:

```
SELECT UserInfo.Name
FROM DriverInfo INNER JOIN UserInfo ON DriverInfo.Email = UserInfo.Email 
    INNER JOIN Agency ON UserInfo.AgencyID = Agency.AgencyID 
WHERE (UserInfo.AgencyID = 1) 
ORDER BY DriverInfo.DriverId DESC
```

2nd query to get vehicles details:

```
SELECT Vehicle.VehicleRegNum AS [Registration Number], 
    Vehicle.EngineNum AS [Engine Number], 
    Vehicle.FileRef AS [File Refrence], 
    Type.Name AS Type, 
    Make.Name AS Make ,
    Vehicle.DriverID AS DriverID
FROM Vehicle INNER JOIN Type ON Vehicle.Type = Type.TypeId 
    INNER JOIN Make ON Vehicle.Make = Make.MakeId 
WHERE (Vehicle.Approve = 1) 
    AND (Vehicle.AgencyId = 1) 
    AND (Vehicle.Maintained = 1) 
ORDER BY Vehicle.VId DESC
```

In this query, I am getting the DriverID
and in the DriverInfo:

```
DriverId, LicenseType, AppointmentDate, LicenseExpiryDate, ContractExpiryDate, Email
```

Comment: How are these two related?  What are the table structures?  I don't see any columns that could be used to relate one query to the other.

Comment: please provide sample input and sample output your question is still unclear

Comment: I think you need to join `DriverInfo` to `Vehicle` on `DriverID`

Comment: Just a quick note, don't use the driver's email address as a foreign key.  When the driver updates their email address, this will create some very difficult updates you will need to make.  Just use the DriverID throughout.

Answer (score 1):

Just add on the additional tables in your join.

```
SELECT Vehicle.VehicleRegNum AS [Registration Number], 
Vehicle.EngineNum AS [Engine Number], 
Vehicle.FileRef AS [File Refrence], 
Type.Name AS Type, 
Make.Name AS Make,
DriverInfo.DriverId,
DriverInfo.LicenseType,
DriverInfo.AppointmentDate,
DriverInfo.LicenseExpiryDate,
DriverInfo.ContractExpiryDate,
DriverInfo.Email
FROM Vehicle 
INNER JOIN Type 
    ON Vehicle.Type = Type.TypeId 
INNER JOIN Make 
    ON Vehicle.Make = Make.MakeId 
INNER JOIN DriverInfo 
    ON Vehicle.DriverID = DriverInfo.DriverId
INNER JOIN UserInfo 
    ON DriverInfo.Email = UserInfo.Email 
INNER JOIN Agency 
    ON UserInfo.AgencyID = Agency.AgencyID 
    AND Vehicle.AgencyID = Agency.AgencyID
WHERE (Vehicle.Approve = 1) 
AND (Vehicle.AgencyId = 1) 
AND (Vehicle.Maintained = 1) 
ORDER BY Vehicle.VId DESC
```

Comment: it's working, but not returning correct data, before that my second query returns 36 records, but your query returns 21 records.

Comment: Like @NickyvV said, you might need to change the joins to suit your needs.  We don't know what type of business rules you have.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following will work, depending on your requirements you might wanna change the `JOIN` type of `DriverInfo`:

```
SELECT Vehicle.VehicleRegNum AS [Registration Number]
    ,Vehicle.EngineNum AS [Engine Number]
    ,Vehicle.FileRef AS [File Refrence]
    ,Type.NAME AS Type
    ,Make.NAME AS Make
    ,UserInfo.NAME AS Driver
FROM Vehicle
INNER JOIN Type ON Vehicle.Type = Type.TypeId
INNER JOIN Make ON Vehicle.Make = Make.MakeId
LEFT JOIN DriverInfo ON DriverInfo.DriverID = Vehicle.DriverID
LEFT JOIN UserInfo ON DriverInfo.Email = UserInfo.Email
    AND (UserInfo.AgencyID = 1)
--Agency is never used, so don't join?
--LEFT JOIN Agency ON UserInfo.AgencyID = Agency.AgencyID
WHERE (Vehicle.Approve = 1)
    AND (Vehicle.AgencyId = 1)
    AND (Vehicle.Maintained = 1)
ORDER BY Vehicle.VId DESC
```

Comment: why you users where clause two times? `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.`

Comment: UserInfo in the where breaks the left join.  Pull that up into the join.